# No matching manifest for linux/arm64 in the manifest list entries? Docker | ARM

Tags: docker, mongodb, mac

После обновления на версию Mac os Sonoma перестал работать образ mongo mongo:3.4.10-jessie.

При этом в настройках докера в разделе Experimental Features исчезла опция эмуляции Rozetta 2.

```
 docker pull --platform linux/arm64 mongo:3.4.10-jessie
```

> 3.4.10-jessie: Pulling from library/mongo
>
> no matching manifest for linux/arm64 in the manifest list entries

Образ можно загрузить указав платформу linux/x86_64:

```
docker pull --platform linux/x86_64 mongo:3.4.10-jessie
```

Но если запускать run то возникает ошибка:

```
docker run  -p 27017:27017 -v /Users/manking/mongoData:/data/db mongo:3.4.10-jessie
```

> WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match
> the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform
> was requested
>
> runtime: failed to create new OS thread (have 2 already; errno=22)
> fatal error: newosproc
>
> runtime stack: runtime.throw(0x4cb21f, 0x9)
> /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:566 +0x95
> runtime.newosproc(0xc420026000, 0xc420035fc0)
> /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os_linux.go:160 +0x194
> runtime.newm(0x4d6db8, 0x0)   /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:1572
> +0x132 runtime.main.func1()   /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:126 +0x36 runtime.systemstack(0x53ae00)   /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:298 +0x79 runtime.mstart()
> /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:1079
>
> goroutine 1 [running]: runtime.systemstack_switch()
> /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:252 fp=0xc420020768
> sp=0xc420020760 runtime.main()    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:127
> +0x6c fp=0xc4200207c0 sp=0xc420020768 runtime.goexit()    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2086 +0x1 fp=0xc4200207c8
> sp=0xc4200207c0

Как запустить старый образ докер версии 3.4.10 который собран под linux на маке в версии Sonoma и выше?